# Find all $x$ and $y$ $(0 \le x, y \lt 2\pi)$ so that the following equation is true.

Tags: trigonometry

Find all $x$ and $y$ $(0 \le x, y \lt 2\pi)$ so that the following equation is true. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

$$(\sin^2x + 1) + i\tan y = 2 \sin x + i$$

$x =$

$y =$

My work:

For $x$:

$$\sin^2x + 1 = 2 \sin x$$

$$\sin^2x - 2\sin x +1 = 0$$

$$x = \pi/2$$

For $y$:

$$\tan y = 1$$

$$y = \arctan(1)$$

$$y = 45\ \ \text{or}\ \ \pi/4$$

I got $x$ correct, but not $y$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Beats me.  What is the allegedly correct answer for $y$?  Do they give any reasoning?

Comment: They don't give me the answers, its online homework where I have to submit my answers to the question. :(

Comment: Ahh, yes, then as mathlove points out, you probably did not give the entire set of values for $y$.

Comment: Yeah I just saw it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$\tan y=1\iff y=\frac{\pi}{4}+n\pi\ \ (n\in\mathbb Z),$$
having
$$0\le y\lt 2\pi$$
gives you $$y=\frac{\pi}{4},\ \color{red}{\frac{5}{4}\pi}.$$

Comment: That answer is correct, so I was supposed to check all solutions for when tan is positive ! Thank you!